# Generating palindromic anagrams of a string of length upto 10^5

Tags: python, chr, ord

I have tried the following but it takes too much time when I try a string of 17 characters.

```
string = input()

def permute(xs, low=0):
    if low + 1 >= len(xs):
        yield xs
    else:
        for p in permute(xs, low + 1):
            yield p        
        for i in range(low + 1, len(xs)):        
            xs[low], xs[i] = xs[i], xs[low]
            for p in permute(xs, low + 1):
                yield p        
            xs[low], xs[i] = xs[i], xs[low]
for p in permute(list(string)):
    mstr = "".join(p)
    if mstr == mstr[::-1]:
        print("YES")
        break
```

This is actually my solution for ['Game of Thrones' challenge on hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-thrones). How can I reduce its execution time and make it run real fast for strings of length 10^5?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using `itertools`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was trying to implement my own method of permutations rather than using a built-in. I want to enhance my coding skills. :)

Comment: But you're asking how to make it faster - using built-ins (written for the most part in C) will be quicker than your own code. Also, recursion isn't always efficient in execution (although it can make complex problems easier to reason about).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have used `itertools`, and let me assure you it takes hell of a long time when the string is even 12 characters long(more than 10mins to find out all the permutations). Of course finding out all the permutations is not going to be an efficient way for doing this- whether you use built-in methods or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying all combination cannot be fast enough, of course. There is a much simpler way to do it. It is based on the following observation: let's assume that `count[c]` is the number of occurrences of `c` in the given string. Then the answer is YES if and only if the number of characters with odd value of `count` is less than or equal to 1. This observation gives a very simple `O(N)` solution.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
count[c] = 0 for each character c that appears in the string
for i = 1...length(s):
    count[s[i]] += 1
with_odd_count = 0
for each c:
    if count[c] % 2 == 1:
        with_odd_count += 1
if with_odd_count <= 1:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: And what if the count is even?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui It does not matter how many characters have even  value of count.

Comment: `number of characters with odd value of count`.. i did not get that.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui for each character `c`, we have computed the value of `count[c]`. It means the number of characters such that `count[c] % 2 == 1`.

Comment: It's always printing out NO.

Comment: @ILoveCoding If the total number of characters is even, then there *must* be *no* characters that appear an odd number of times. Similarly, if the total character count is odd, there *must* be *exactly one* character that occurs an odd number of times.

Comment: @twalberg If my code prints "YES",  all these conditions are satisfied, anyway(it is easy to prove by looking at the parity of the length and the number of occurrences of each character). So there is no need to check them explicitly.

Comment: @ILoveCoding Yes - that was more a comment on your "if and only if the number of characters with odd value of count is less than or equal to 1", as further clarification...